# kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code 2 - kCFHostErrorUnknown

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, cfnetwork

I am having an error when trying to change an iFrame's location.

> WebSocket network error: The operation cannot be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code 2)

I am having this exception on Safari Mobile (iPad). This error does not occur on Safari Desktop.

kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code 2 is kCFHostErrorUnknown. But, what does this mean and how can I fix this?

According to the documentation,

> kCFHostErrorUnknown
>
> An unknown error occurred (a name server failure, for example). For additional information, you can query the kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey key to obtain the value returned by getaddrinfo and look up the value in /usr/include/netdb.h.

Where can I query the kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey? Also, I don't think I can look up netdb.h.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Since I am using IP Address to access the server. The WebSocket server should also be IP Address.